# ROOT installation on MacOs

Tags: installation, path, homebrew, root, zshrc

ROOT is required as a pre-requisite for some software that I am trying to install. I'm on a MacOs system and I have tried to install using `brew install root`. Do I need to do anything else? How can I check that root was successfully installed?

When I tried to install said software, apparently files in the root directory cannot be found, e.g. error

`/usr/local/Cellar/root/6.22.06_1/etc/root/cling/lib/clang/5.0.0/include/assert.h:8:15: fatal error: 'assert.h' file not found`

I have checked this manually and the file is there so I don't understand why it is not found. I also tried the following line in my .zshrc file

`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/root/6.22.06_1/etc/root/cling/lib/clang/5.0.0/include/assert.h`

and

`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/thisroot.sh`

Any ideas of what may be going wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: This is the homebrew package 'root', right?
https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/root
completely unrelated to the user 'root' or the '/' directory.